# Micronaut 3: How to use PubSubEmulatorContainer

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, micronaut, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

Update: Link to repo is moved to answer because repo is now updated with code from answer below.

**Problem description**

Current code is working, but it is using *gcloud beta emulators pubsub* from *google/cloud-sdk* for integration tests.

- Integration tests are slow due to the size of the *google/cloud-sdk* image
- pubsub emulator has to run on a fixed port, there seems to be no way to tell Micronaut which port the emulator is running on

I'll need to set the following environment variable in `maven-surefire-plugin`.

```
<environmentVariables>
    <PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST>localhost:8085</PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST>
</environmentVariables>
```

**How this can be done in Spring Boot**

According to Test Containers | Gcloud Module, the correct way of implementing integration tests with *PubSubEmulatorContainer* in Spring Boot is like this:
https://github.com/saturnism/testcontainers-gcloud-examples/blob/main/springboot/pubsub-example/src/test/java/com/example/springboot/pubsub/PubSubIntegrationTests.java

This will bring up the container on a random port, and that is possible because of `DynamicPropertyRegistry` in Spring. It seems that Micronaut is missing this possibility.

Doc: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/gcloud/

---

I'm looking for a working example of a JUnit5 or Spock integration test implemented in Micronaut 3.x that is using `PubSubEmulatorContainer` like described in the above doc.

Related doc: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gcp/latest/guide/#emulator

---

There are some comments on GitHub around configuring `TransportChannelProvider`. I'm able to inject an instance and inspect it, but I still haven't found out exactly what to do.

These are the closest leads so far:
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gcp/issues/257
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gcp/pull/259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2023-07-23** Bumped to Micronaut 4.0.1, refactored away Lombok in Java-demo. Link: [pubsub-emulator-demo repo](https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/pubsub-emulator-demo)

**Update 2023-05-01** Updated [pubsub-emulator-demo repo](https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/pubsub-emulator-demo) with Kotlin/Kotest-example.

**TL;DR**

We'll need to start the testcontainer first, get emulator host address and then call `ApplicationContext.run` like this:

```
applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(               
["pubsub.emulator.host": emulatorHost])
```

Small Github repo with example code: https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/pubsub-emulator-demo

**Long answer with code**

I finally managed to make a working solution using Micronaut 3.0.2 and Spock. A related Micronaut PR got me on track, together with this article: *Micronaut Testing Best Practices* https://objectcomputing.com/files/9815/9259/7089/slide_deck_Micronaut_Testing_Best_Practices_webinar.pdf

First a *PubSubEmulator* class (Groovy)

```
package no.myproject.testframework.testcontainers

import org.testcontainers.containers.PubSubEmulatorContainer
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName

class PubSubEmulator {
    static PubSubEmulatorContainer pubSubEmulatorContainer

    static init() {
        if (pubSubEmulatorContainer == null) {
            pubSubEmulatorContainer = new PubSubEmulatorContainer(
                    DockerImageName.parse("gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:emulators"))
            pubSubEmulatorContainer.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Then a fixture for PubSubEmulator (Groovy)

```
package no.myproject.testframework.testcontainers

trait PubSubEmulatorFixture {
    Map<String, Object> getPubSubConfiguration() {
        if (PubSubEmulator.pubSubEmulatorContainer == null || !PubSubEmulator.pubSubEmulatorContainer.isRunning()) {
            PubSubEmulator.init()
        }
        [
                "pubsub.emulator-host": PubSubEmulator.pubSubEmulatorContainer.getEmulatorEndpoint()
        ]
    }
}
```

Then a specification class (Groovy) that starts the container, creates a topic and a subscription.

The clue here is to pass in `pubsub.emulator.host` as part of the configuration when calling `ApplicationContext.run`.

Remaining part of the code is very similar to the Spring Boot example I linked to in my question.

```
package no.myproject.testframework

import com.google.api.gax.core.NoCredentialsProvider
import com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcTransportChannel
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.FixedTransportChannelProvider
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminSettings
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminSettings
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PushConfig
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import no.myproject.configuration.GcpConfigProperties
import no.myproject.configuration.PubSubConfigProperties
import no.myproject.testframework.testcontainers.PubSubEmulatorFixture
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

abstract class PubSubSpecification extends Specification
        implements PubSubEmulatorFixture, EnvironmentFixture {

    @AutoCleanup
    @Shared
    EmbeddedServer embeddedServer

    @AutoCleanup
    @Shared
    ApplicationContext applicationContext

    def setupSpec() {

        // start the pubsub emulator
        def emulatorHost = getPubSubConfiguration().get("pubsub.emulator-host")

        // start a temporary applicationContext in order to read config
        // keep any pubsub subscriptions out of context at this stage
        applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run()

        def gcpConfigProperties = applicationContext.getBean(GcpConfigProperties)
        def pubSubConfigProperties = applicationContext.getBean(PubSubConfigProperties)

        def channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("dns:///" + emulatorHost)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build()

        def channelProvider =
                FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel))

        // START creating topic

        def topicAdminClient =
                TopicAdminClient.create(
                        TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                                .setCredentialsProvider(NoCredentialsProvider.create())
                                .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                                .build())

        def topic = TopicName.of(
                gcpConfigProperties.getProjectId(),
                pubSubConfigProperties.getTopicName())

        try {
            topicAdminClient.createTopic(topic)
        } catch (AlreadyExistsException) {
            // this is fine, already created
            topicAdminClient.getTopic(topic)
        }

        // START creating subscription

        pubSubConfigProperties.getSubscriptionNames().forEach(it -> {
            def subscription =
                    ProjectSubscriptionName.of(gcpConfigProperties.getProjectId(), it)

            def subscriptionAdminClient =
                    SubscriptionAdminClient.create(
                            SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                                    .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                                    .setCredentialsProvider(NoCredentialsProvider.create())
                                    .build())

            try {
                subscriptionAdminClient
                        .createSubscription(
                                subscription,
                                topic,
                                PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(),
                                100)

                System.out.println("Subscription created " + subscriptionAdminClient.getSubscription(subscription))
            } catch (AlreadyExistsException) {
                // this is fine, already created
                subscriptionAdminClient.getSubscription(subscription)
            }
        })

        channel.shutdown()

        // stop the temporary applicationContext
        applicationContext.stop()

        // start the actual applicationContext
        embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(
                EmbeddedServer,
                [
                        'spec.name'           : "PubSubEmulatorSpec",
                        "pubsub.emulator.host": emulatorHost
                ],
                environments)

        applicationContext = embeddedServer.applicationContext
    }
}
```

Then a factory class (Groovy) for mocking credentials

```
package no.myproject.pubsub

import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Replaces
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires

import javax.inject.Singleton


@Factory
@Requires(property = 'spec.name', value = 'PubSubEmulatorSpec')
class EmptyCredentialsFactory {

    @Singleton
    @Replaces(GoogleCredentials)
    GoogleCredentials mockCredentials() {
        return GoogleCredentials.create(new AccessToken("", new Date()))
    }
}
```

And finally, a Spock test spec.

```
package no.myproject.pubsub

import no.myproject.testframework.PubSubSpecification

import java.util.stream.IntStream

class PubSubIntegrationSpec extends PubSubSpecification {

    def NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_IN_TEST = 5
    def DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS_PER_MSG = 100

    def "when a number of messages is sent, same amount of messages is received"() {
        given:
        def documentPublisher = applicationContext.getBean(DocumentPublisher)
        def listener = applicationContext.getBean(IncomingDocListenerWithAck)
        def initialReceiveCount = listener.getReceiveCount()

        when:
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_IN_TEST)
                .forEach(it -> documentPublisher.send("Hello World!"))

        // wait a bit in order to let all messages propagate through the queue
        Thread.sleep(NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_IN_TEST * DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS_PER_MSG)

        then:
        NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_IN_TEST == listener.getReceiveCount() - initialReceiveCount
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer is a good deal more complicated than necessary, and it also contains numerous typos. A better answer can be found via the [Micronaut  GCP codebase itself](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gcp/blob/master/gcp-pubsub/src/test/groovy/io/micronaut/gcp/pubsub/integration/IntegrationTestSpec.groovy), with the key bit being:

```
class IntegrationTestSpec extends Specification {

    static CONTAINER_PORT = -1
    static CredentialsProvider CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER
    static TransportChannelProvider TRANSPORT_CHANNEL_PROVIDER
    static PubSubResourceAdmin pubSubResourceAdmin

    static GenericContainer pubSubContainer = new GenericContainer("google/cloud-sdk:292.0.0")
        .withCommand("gcloud", "beta", "emulators", "pubsub", "start", "--project=test-project",
                "--host-port=0.0.0.0:8085")
        .withExposedPorts(8085)
        .waitingFor(new LogMessageWaitStrategy().withRegEx("(?s).*Server started, listening on.*"))

    static {
        pubSubContainer.start()
        CONTAINER_PORT = pubSubContainer.getMappedPort(8085)
        CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER = NoCredentialsProvider.create()
        def host = "localhost:" + IntegrationTest.CONTAINER_PORT
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(host).usePlaintext().build()
        TRANSPORT_CHANNEL_PROVIDER =
                FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel))
        pubSubResourceAdmin = new PubSubResourceAdmin(TRANSPORT_CHANNEL_PROVIDER, CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER)
    }
}
```

You'd then just extend that class anywhere you wanted to make use of PubSub. The following is slightly cleaner example that I came up with which manages creating a topic as well during test startup:

```
@Slf4j
abstract class PubSubSpec extends Specification implements TestPropertyProvider {

    static final String cloudSdkName = System.getenv('CLOUD_SDK_IMAGE') ?: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:emulators"
    static final DockerImageName cloudSdkImage = DockerImageName.parse(cloudSdkName)
    static final PubSubEmulatorContainer pubsubEmulator = new PubSubEmulatorContainer(cloudSdkImage)

    static {
        pubsubEmulator.start()
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(pubsubEmulator.getEmulatorEndpoint()).usePlaintext().build()
        try {
            TransportChannelProvider channelProvider = FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel))
            CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create()
            TopicAdminClient topicClient = TopicAdminClient.create(
                TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                    .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .build()
            )
            TopicName topicName = TopicName.of("project-id", "project-topic")
            topicClient.createTopic(topicName)
        } finally {
            channel.shutdown()
        }
    }

    @Override
    Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        [
            "pubsub.emulator.host": pubsubEmulator.getEmulatorEndpoint()
        ]
    }
}
```